# Java UI Controls alike as .NET

Tags: java, .net, wpf

I am new to Java, is there any library or framework that allows me to customize user controls (customize appearance, events etc) similar to .NET, just like in WPF? My friend recommend swing. Is it feasible?

Comment: No, there's nothing like WPF in Java world. You can find something similar to WinForms, but that's it. The only *real* competitor of WPF is Qt, but it's C++. Prepare to feel pain.

Comment: [java](http://www.lr21.com.uy/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/carro-caballo-animalecqus.org-1.jpg) doesn't look like a good option if you need a Rich UI. You should seriously consider whether it's worth to use an inferior technology. Do you need to target non Windows platforms?

Answer (score 0):

swing is the old way.

since Java 1.8 you can use FXML

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm